# Gradients and Quiver plots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
from scipy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_elines(x_grid, y_grid, potential, field):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 13))
    im_cs = ax.contour(x_grid, y_grid, potential, 18, cmap='inferno')
    plt.clabel(im_cs, inline=1, fontsize=7)
    ax.quiver(x_grid[::3, ::3], y_grid[::3, ::3],
              field[0, ::3, ::3], field[1, ::3, ::3],)
    ax.set_xlabel("$x$")
    ax.set_ylabel("$y$")
    plt.show()


# define q configuration (x,y positions)
charges = [
    [1, 1],
]

xx, yy = meshgrid(linspace(-4, 4), linspace(-4, 4))
# potential function
e_pot = 0.
for idx, q in enumerate(charges):
    dx, dy = xx-q[0], yy-q[1]
    rr = hypot(dx, dy)
    e_pot += 1/(4*pi) * 1./rr
e_field = gradient(-e_pot)
e_field /= hypot(e_field[0], e_field[1]) * 5

# why is this needed?
e_field[0] = e_field[0].T
e_field[1] = e_field[1].T

plot_elines(xx, yy, e_pot, e_field)
```

I have a question about using the `gradient` function from numpy/scipy.

I am plotting here the electric field equipotential lines and the field vectors of a single positive charge. The definition is

> E = -grad(V)

By definition, the field vectors (quiver) and equipotential lines (contour) are supposed to be orthogonal to each other at all points in space, and since the charge is positive, the arrows need to point away from the charge itself.

I am using scipy's `gradient` function to calculate E, but I found that the output is wrong if I don't transpose the x-y grid output by the `gradient` function.

Compare the two outputs (with `.T` (correct) and without `.T` (wrong)):

[image: right]
vs
[image: wrong]

Why is the transpose needed? Or am I plotting something wrongly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the transpose gives you the correct plot is by pure coincidence, because the charge is possitionned symmetrical in x and y (i.e. on the 45° line).

The real problem comes from the wrong interpretation of `numpy.gradient`. It will return the gradient axis-wise. The first array for the axis 0 and the second for axis 1. Now, axis 0 in your case corresponds to the `y` axis, and axis 1 to the `x` axis.

```
e_field_y, e_field_x = numpy.gradient(-e_pot)
```

So when you select the respective field components in the quiver plot, you need to choose the first entry as the y component and the second as the x component.

```
ax.quiver(x_grid[::3, ::3], y_grid[::3, ::3],
          field[1, ::3, ::3], field[0, ::3, ::3],)
```

The complete code would then look like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_elines(x_grid, y_grid, potential, field):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 13))
    im_cs = ax.contour(x_grid, y_grid, potential, 18, cmap='inferno')
    plt.clabel(im_cs, inline=1, fontsize=7)
    ax.quiver(x_grid[::3, ::3], y_grid[::3, ::3],
              field[1, ::3, ::3], field[0, ::3, ::3],)
    ax.set_xlabel("$x$")
    ax.set_ylabel("$y$")
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
    plt.show()


# define q configuration (x,y positions)
charges = [
    [1, 0],
]

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-4, 4), np.linspace(-4, 4))
# potential function
e_pot = 0.
for idx, q in enumerate(charges):
    dx, dy = xx-q[0], yy-q[1]
    rr = np.hypot(dx, dy)
    e_pot += 1/(4*np.pi) * 1./rr
e_field = np.gradient(-e_pot)
e_field /= np.hypot(e_field[0], e_field[1]) * 5

plot_elines(xx, yy, e_pot, e_field)
```

where I put the charge off the anti-diagonal.

[image]

A final hint: A good consistency check for such codes is if you use non-identical shaped grids. E.g. if you take 50 points along x and 51 along y, you would have gotten an error instead of a seemingly working code and would be directed more easily towards the underlying problem.

Comment: can you elaborate a little why axis 0 is the yaxis in my case? is it because of the output of meshgrid?

Comment: Well, it's in a sense your choice, because you call the arrays `xx` and `yy` and later in the call to contour and quiver expect the x to be your x values. But that choice makes sense, because then in the array rows correspond to y which is usually the vertical axis of a plot.